# Infragistics Wintabs - Walking controls on Tab misses Shared controls

Tags: .net, infragistics

My issue is pretty sraight forward. I have three tabs on an UltraWinTab and a routine which walks all the controls on a tab. I pass to it an Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabPageControl instance and it walks the controls collection on that tab.

It does NOT appear to get the visible "shared controls" when I do this using

```
For each ctrl in TabPageControl
```

when the tab is not visible. It gets all the non-shared controls just fine. I recently updated to 2014.1 release.

HOW do I get all the controls would be visible on a tab on an UltraTabControl? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean, `For each ctrl in TabPageControl.**Controls**`?

Comment: You probably need to do `For each ctrl in TabPageControl.SharedControls`. **SharedControls** is collection of shared controls on `UltraTabControl`

Comment: Ok. That gives me entire list of shared controls for UltraTabConrol. I need to know which fields are being displayed on a certain UltraTagPageControl in order to blank out the data fiels on that particular tab. How do I determine if it is used on my current UltraTagPageControl that I am verifying?

Comment: Try this:  `foreach (var t in tc.Tabs) 
            {
               foreach (var c in t.TabPage.Controls)
               {
                   
               } 
            }`
Pass your tab but then take a tab's page and iterate controls on it

Comment: Thank You for your suggestions. I am able to resolve the issue by walking both collections.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by walking the entire UltraTabPageControl.Controls collection and the UltraTabControl.SharedControls collection looking for the Visible = True property. This gives ALL the controls on a Tab.